# Looking for Coldfusion UDF to insert br without splitting a word in the middle

Tags: coldfusion, user-defined-functions

Like the title says, I'm looking to insert a <br> if the title contains more characters than what will fit in the display.  I know it exists but i simply cannot find it and would really like some help on this one.

Comment: The UDF that I'm thinking of has been used to trim text and add Read More... if that helps joggles anyone's memory.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=329

Comment: Good ole' FullLeft(). Great function. I use it all the time.